# gpg2: How to get rid of "Please insert card with serial number", getting the same key from a different card / Yubikey

Tags: gnupg, smartcard, yubikey

I have multiple Yubikeys carrying the same GPG secret key. I want to switch from one Yubikey to anohter one on my laptop. The two obviously have different serial numbers.

After switching the keys when I try to decrypt something (e.g. with [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/)), I get a popup:

```
Please insert card with serial number XXXXXXXXXX
```

(This is with GnuPG version 2.2.17.)

How can I get rid of the popup, telling `gpg` to ignore whatever the serial number of the smart card is that I used so far, and instead to look for whatever card has the private key that I'm trying to use?

Comment: I have this issue on my linux desktop as well. Strangely this all just works how you'd expect on Mac with GPG installed through homebrew.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Solution

**Delete the keygrips of the keys in question from `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d`.**

You can list the keygrip IDs using `gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip`.

If **all** your private keys are on external cards like the Yubikey, you can delete them all using:

```
rm -r ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
```

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548260/what-is-in-this-directory-home-gnupg-private-keys-v1-d-and-where-are-the-pri) for more information about the `private-keys-v1.d` directory.

---

After the deletion of the keygrips, it seems beneficial to run

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
gpg --card-status
```

to restart the gpg-agent and reload the card info.

### Extra info: What happens when you don't restart/reload (for people who search for these error messages)

If you do only `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`, the next decryption may show

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Reloading the card info fixes that.

If you do only `gpg --card-edit`, the next decryption may show

```
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such file or directory
```

Restarting the agent before that fixes that.

Personally I consider that a bad user experience, ideally GPG would automatically figure that out, but I don't know any technical details about it.

Comment: I found out after you delete the private key directory, you only need to run gpg --card-status and everything will work.

Comment: It looks like this will be fixed a future version of gnupg:
https://dev.gnupg.org/T1983

Comment: When I follow these steps I now get an `agent refused operation` error.